# PHP Wordpress is_home piece of code

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I want something that can show a certain piece of code on the home page, but something else on all the other pages.

I'm looking for something like:

```
<?php is_front_page() 
If true ( the-piece-of-code-I-wanna-use-on-the-homepage )
Else ( the-code-I-want-to-use-on-every-other-page )
; ?>
```

I know the above is wrong :P, I'm not that good with php. But I hope somebody can give me something that would work.

Cheers.

Edit:
I would like it to be something like this:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){ echo "
        <?php
            // Check to see if the header image has been removed
            $header_image = get_header_image();
            if ( $header_image ) :
                // Compatibility with versions of WordPress prior to 3.4.
                if ( function_exists( 'get_custom_header' ) ) {
                    // We need to figure out what the minimum width should be for our featured image.
                    // This result would be the suggested width if the theme were to implement flexible widths.
                    $header_image_width = get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'width' );
                } else {
                    $header_image_width = HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH;
                }
                ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
            <?php
                // The header image
                // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                if ( is_singular() && has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                        ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( $header_image_width, $header_image_width ) ) ) &&
                        $image[1] >= $header_image_width ) :
                    // Houston, we have a new header image!
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                else :
                    // Compatibility with versions of WordPress prior to 3.4.
                    if ( function_exists( 'get_custom_header' ) ) {
                        $header_image_width  = get_custom_header()->width;
                        $header_image_height = get_custom_header()->height;
                    } else {
                        $header_image_width  = HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH;
                        $header_image_height = HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
                    }
                    ?>
                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
            <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>
"; } else { echo "
 <?php if ( function_exists( 'show_simpleresponsiveslider' ) ) show_simpleresponsiveslider(); ?>
 <?php if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) : "; ?>
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()){
    echo "code here for front page";
} else {
    echo "code for other pages";
} ?>
```

That should be what you're looking for. The is_front_page() function will either return true or false, then show the correct code.

Comment: Hi, could you perhaps edit this code in such a way that 'code-here-for-front-page' can be another PHP code?

To be precise, something like this:
<?php
if(is_front_page()){
    echo "
 <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
";
} else {
    echo "
 if ( function_exists( 'show_simpleresponsiveslider' ) ) show_simpleresponsiveslider(); ?>
   <?php
    // Has the text been hidden?
    if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) :
   
   ";
} ?>

Comment: I was going to do it, then you updated your post with about 5 times the amount of code. I'd suggest going back and learning proper PHP syntax and semantics

Comment: Hy MrHunter, I didn't realize that adding PHP inside a PHP code wouldn't work. I'm quite a n00b when it comes to PHP and HTML.
I finished adding now :P I won't add anything more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_home function.

```
<?php
if (is_home()) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home